# Not able to display response data on html page

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I got the response data from ajax query and i am able to see that in console.log function. But now i want to display the username stored in an object.

**display.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    LoadUserScript(ReadUser);
});
```

**devlope.js**

```
function LoadUserScript(callback){
    function LoadUser(){
        $.getScript('js/user.js', callback);
    }
    if (!$.fn.user){
        LoadUser();
    }
    else {
        if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    }
}

function ReadUser(){
    var readUser = new users.user;
    readUser.ReadUserDetail("gourav", "pwd");
    readUser.PrintUserDetail(); //This is Printing the 
}
```

**user.js**

```
(function (){
    "use strict";
    var root = this;
    var users;
    if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        users = exports;
    } else {
        users = root.users = {};
    }

    var user = users.user = function () {
        this.ap = [];
        this.tg = [];
        this.userdetails = [];
    };

    var user = users.user = function (username, userpassword) {
        this.username = username;
        this.name = "";
        this.userpassword= userpassword;
        this.ap = [];
        this.tg = [];
        this.userdetails = [];
        this.url = "http://localhost/RestApi/ReadUser";
    };

    user.prototype.fillUserDetail = function ( response, handle) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        handle.name = obj.name;
        handle.username = obj.login;
        if(obj.AccountDetail)
        {
            handle.userdetails = obj.AccountDetail;
        }
        if(obj.ap)
        {
            handle.ap = obj.ap;
        }
        if(obj.tg)
        {
            handle.tg = obj.tg;
        }
    };

    user.prototype.PrintUserDetail = function(){
        console.log(this.username);
        console.log(this.name);
        console.log(this.userdetails);
        console.log(this.ap);
    };

    user.prototype.ReadUserDetail = function (username, userpassword)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.userpassword = userpassword;
        var sentdata = {"login":this.username, "pwd":this.userpassword};
        var callback = this.fillUserDetail;
        var localhandle = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: this.url,
            data: JSON.stringify(sentdata),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(response){
                callback(response, localhandle);
            },
            error: function (xhr, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
            },
            async: false
        });
    };
}).call(this);
```

Now i am getting all the object values correct when i call `ReadUser()` from **devlope.js** which means all the data are correct in `readUser` variable. 
Now in display.html i want to display the field name which i got from the response and stored in field `readUser.name`.

```
<div class="col-style">
    <div class="sparkboard" id="sparkboard-1"></div>
    <div class="sparkboard-info">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o" >Hello <readUser.name> ???
        </i>
    </div>
</div>
```

But i am not sure how i should access `readUser.name` next to Hello in .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a span element in HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-smile-o" >
    <span id="readusername"></span>
</i>
```

And access & fill it in JS from your variable:

```
document.querySelector('#readusername').textContent = readUser.name;
```

Comment: where should i put this document.querySelector ?

Comment: Right after the script received the user name, just where you printed it to the console. That would be the callback ReadUser(). If I get your code right. Not sure if this is good code design, but it should work for a first test.

Answer (score 0):

Put this

```
<i class="fa fa-smile-o" >
  <span id="yourSpanID"></span>
</i>
```

instead of

```
<i class="fa fa-smile-o" >Hello <readUser.name> ???
        </i>
```

and add this code to your callback ReadUser

```
$('#yourSpanID').textContent = readUser.name;
```